# a variant of shortest path problem

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Can someone help me on how I can approach this problem- all I can think of is recursively calling a function(but that doesn't really seem to work).

Let's say I start with zero and add either of two numbers at each step. So, at first I may add n1 or n2 to zero; so the new no. becomes n1 or n2, then add either of n1 or n2.

Doing this, how can I find whether or not a certain number, say N, is ever reached? And if the number is reached, how can I find the shortest path for it to reach N (solution could be something like n1,n1,n2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks more like a [linear Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations) with non-negativity constraints than like a shortest path problem.

To summarize from the article: if d is the greatest common divisor of n<sub>1</sub> and n<sub>2</sub>, then there is a solution if and only if N is a multiple of d. If it is, then there an infinity of solutions (including a smallest one), which can be found by the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). You just have to do a little (hah!) extra work to determine if there is a smallest solution in non-negative integers. (E.g., there is no non-negative solution for 2n<sub>1</sub> + 3n<sub>2</sub> = 1.)

Comment: "there is a solution if and only if N is a multiple of d" - not true. check n1=3 n2=4 N=5.

Comment: @yi_H, GCD of 3 and 4 is 1. And 5 is a multiple of 1.

Comment: @svick: yes and there are no x and y such that 3x+4y=5 such that x and y are non-negative integers. Therefore it's slightly wrong. It's not an iff but a reverse implication.

Comment: @harold, it's not wrong the way Ted said id. He said that if the condition holds, there are solutions. But maybe they are not non-negative and you have to figure that out as a second step.

Comment: @svick: it is wrong. But that was the part where he was summarizing the article. It isn't "if", but "only if" is true.

Comment: @harold - Perhaps you are interpreting "then there is a solution" at the start of the second paragraph to mean a solution to OP's problem. That's not what I meant; this was referring to any solutions to the (unconstrainted) linear Diophantine equation. I thought it was clear that I was summarizing the article at that point.

Answer (score 1):

arrange the numbers so that n1>n2

repeatedly substruct n2 from N (result in M) till M % n1 = 0 and M>=0. That will give you the optimal solution, N = (M / n1) * n1 + rest * n2.

If your algorithm fails to find an M after n1 steps there is no solution.